# IDEA Grails Unit Test for UrlMappings

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am using Grails 2.3.7 .I wanted to unit test UrlMappings.groovy,so I created a Unit test using create unit test command.However INtell complains of the compile error when in the line with "@TestFor(UrlMappings)".Says UrlMappings cannot be resolved.Confused on why.See image 
below

[image]

When I run the test I get :

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add UrlMappings class [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings]. It is not a UrlMappings!
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:834)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:538)
>       at grails.test.mixin.web.UrlMappingsUnitTestMixin.mockUrlMappings(UrlMappingsUnitTestMixin.groovy:51)
>       at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
>       at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
>       at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
>       at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ? I do not see this issue in 12.1. And shouldn't the name of spec end with `*Spec` ?

Comment: I am using 13.1.I tried even with the one ending with Spec.Apparently that does not seem to be the problem here...:(

Comment: @fmahapatro..Are you sure there is no compile error?For me it complains and ultimately test throws exception

Comment: Yes. That is what I see in the IDE. Btw, why is the import for UrlMappings commented out?

Answer (score 0):

ahh..I thought the class under grails-app/conf will be imported automatically.My bad..I created another UrlMappings class inside same package as test and it worked..Thanks for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: [Docs indicate](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/testing.html#unitTestingURLMappings) that the test has to be in the default package as `UrlMappings` is in a default package under `grails-app/conf`